# Multi-Row Per Record SQL Statement

Tags: sql, report, servicenow

I'm not sure this is possible but my manager wants me to do it...

Using the below picture as a reference, is it possible to retrieve a group of records, where each record has 2 rows of columns?

So columns: Number, Incident Number, Vendor Number, Customer Name, Customer Location, Status, Opened and Updated would be part of the first row and column: Work Notes would be a new row that spans the width of the report. Each record would have two rows. Is this possible with a GROUP BY statement?

**Record 1**

Row 1 = Number, Incident Number, Vendor Number, Customer Name, Customer Location, Status, Opened and Updated

Row 2 = Work Notes

**Record 2**

Row 1 = Number, Incident Number, Vendor Number, Customer Name, Customer Location, Status, Opened and Updated

Row 2 = Work Notes

**Record *n***

...

[image: PDF Export]

Comment: Why can't you simply include the Work Notes field in the same row with the rest of the data? What are you hoping to accomplish by retrieving the data the way you describe? If you don't need the Work Notes field right away, why can't just run a separate query later to grab it when you need it? I don't know if what you're asking is possible, but I don't see how it would be useful either, sometimes the best solution is to keep things simple if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that possible with the built in report engine. You'll need to export the data and format it using something else.

You could have something similar to what you want on short description (list report, group by short description), but you can't group by work notes so that's out.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that the `work_notes` field is not actually a field on the table, the `work_notes` field is of type `journal_input`, which means it's really just a gateway to the actual underlying data model. "Modifying" `work_notes` actually just inserts into `sys_journal_field`.

`sys_journal_field` is the table which stores the work notes you're looking for. Given a sys_id of an incident record, this URL will give you all journal field entries for that particular record:

```
/sys_journal_field_list.do?sysparm_query=name=task^element_id=<YOUR_SYS_ID>
```

You will notice this includes ALL journal fields (comments + work_notes + anything else), so if you just wanted work notes, you could simply add a query against `element` thusly:

```
/sys_journal_field_list.do?sysparm_query=name=task^element=work_notes^element_id=<YOUR_SYS_ID>
```

**What this means for you!**

While you can't separate a physical row into multiple logical rows in the UI, in the case of journal fields you *can* join your target table against the `sys_journal_field` table using a Database View. This deviates from your goal in that you wouldn't get a single row for all work notes, but rather an additional row for each matched work note.

Given an incident INC123 with 3 work notes, your report against the Database View would look kind of like this:

> - Row 1: INT123 | markmilly | This is a test incident |
> - Row 2: INT123 | | | Work note #1
> - Row 3: INT123 | | | Work note #2
> - Row 4: INT123 | | | Work note #3